# How to disable "password contains the user name" restriction in centos 7

Tags: linux, centos, passwords

My username is z, and my password contains z, and the system disallow me to use that password. The error is:

> BAD PASSWORD: The password contains the user name in some form.

This is an error and I cannot get pass through. I Googled about this problem but cannot find any working answer. These are the things I tried:

- Call passwd from root.
- Change /etc/pam.d/system-auth and /etc/pam.d/password-auth: from requisite to optional on pam_pwquality.so or comment out that line. Commenting out result in error "passwd: Authentication token manipulation error".
- Check /usr/sbin/authconfig --help, find no related option.
- Change /etc/security/pwquality.conf, find no related option. Tried gecoscheck=0, didn't make any different.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: This `password contains the user name` restriction is meant for the security. Why you want to bypass that ?

Comment: @C0deDaedalus, because he is using such a short username, the options for password are significantly limited (`91^length` rather than `92^length` which for any reasonable length will eliminate millions or billions of passwords from selection), and thus signifigantly reduces the keyspace the password can be drawn from. the most secure choice would be to select a much longer username, but failing that, the rule is doing more harm than good in this specific case.

Comment: @FrankThomas, totally agree on that.

Comment: Can't you change your user name to `zw`, for example? Not the answer you are looking for, but maybe the easiest work-round.

Comment: I always use z as my username and don't want to change that. I known change username can be an option, but I just want to find the way to solve this.

Answer (score 3):

Checking libpwquality [code on github](https://github.com/libpwquality/libpwquality/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=++++++BAD+PASSWORD%3A+The+password+contains+the+user+name+in+some+form.&type=) it looks like error message you get comes from this library. Probably called from PAM module, so you should start checking what you have in `/etc/pam.d/passwd` by default for password it only includes `/etc/pam.d/system-auth`. I think you were quite close, however, setting module as optional didn't work for you. I'd suggest commenting it out for test and setting `gecoscheck=N` either in pam or `/etc/security/pwquality.conf`

Simply commenting out the line in `/etc/pam.d/system-auth` may not work, however, you can try to update the file password section to something like this (only password section matters):

`password    sufficient    pam_unix.so sha512
password    required      pam_deny.so`

After that simply execute `passwd user` at try your favourite password. For me setting exectly the same user name and password worked, which is obviously not recommended from the system security perspective.

Comment: Commenting out that line result in error "passwd: Authentication token manipulation error", and setting gecoscheck=N or gecoscheck=0 not making any different.

Comment: I think it's because of some arguments of next password modules, try to update your /etc/pam.d/system-auth changing password section to this:
`password    sufficient    pam_unix.so sha512
password    required      pam_deny.so`. I've also updated the answer, since formatting there makes it easier to read.

Comment: It works! To clarify, I commented out the pam_pwquality.so line and change the following line as this answer say and it let me pass. Thank you very much!

Comment: yw, If you can click the up arrow for the answer I'll appreciate it - I'm new to the community so every point counts.

Comment: I would like to do that but I cannot, I don't have enough reputations...

Answer (score 1):

Yet another way is to copy the encrypted password from an existing password file (on another PC).

This means copying the password from the user *myuser* from the `/etc/shadow` file on one PC, without strict password checks:

```
[..]
sshd:!!:19571::::::
postfix:!!:19571::::::
myuser:$6$<some crypted login>:18472:0:99999:7:::
[..]
```

to the PC with more stickt password rules. Just copy the encrypted password

```
$6$<some crypted login>
```

into the new password file between the second and third colon `:` ($6$ is the type of encryption, the actual encrypted password is removed in this example).

You might also want a check of the `/etc/passwd` and  `/etc/shadow` file ala

```
> pwck -r /etc/passwd /etc/shadow
user 'ftp': directory '/var/ftp' does not exist
pwck: no changes
```

(and a system reboot might be needed before the password change takes effect!?)

Answer (score 0):

Change the below option in /etc/pam.d/password.aut and /etc/pam.d/system.auth file

[image: screenshot]

This is working fine but need to put 4 times password.

Answer (score -1):

I just tested,Call passwd from root will force update the user password although it will still show a warning message "BAD PASSWORD: The password contains the user name in some form "
But the actual update works.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).